# Creating customize theme variant for Button in Native Base (changing disabled colors)

Tags: react-native, native-base

I'm recently using Native Base in my React Native app.
I'm creating my customize theme and creating some variant for my buttons.
I want to change background color if button is disabled.

These are default native base variants
[https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/blob/v3-pre-beta/src/theme/components/button.ts] and I've seen how they're using `props.isDisabled` to change some props.
But for me console.log are sending me `undefined`
Here is my code

```
  import { extendTheme } from 'native-base'
  import { Dict } from 'native-base/lib/typescript/theme/tools'

  const variantLogin = (props: Dict) => {
    console.log('const is disabled', props.isDisabled)
    return {
      bg: props.isDisabled
        ? theme?.colors?.gray['200']
        : theme?.colors?.orange?.main,
      _text: {
        color: props.isDisabled
          ? theme?.colors?.gray['500']
          : theme?.colors?.white,
      },
    }
  }


  export const theme = extendTheme({
    colors: {
      white: '#ffffff',
      black: '#000000',
      gray: {
        100: '#f5f5f5',
        200: '#d8d8d8',
        300: '#c4c4c4',
        500: '#828282',
        800: '#4b4a4a',
        900: '#1a1a1a',
      },
      gold: {
        main: '#e7c14d',
      },
    },
  components: {
    Button: {
      variants: {
        login: variantLogin
      }
    }
  }
})

export default theme
```

Color changes right with

```
  <Button isDisabled={disabled} variant={'login'}>{text}</NativeButton>
```

It shows and orange button with white letters, but not when is disabled, only more transparency appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there's a way to pass `isDisabled` prop, but here's a way to solve it:

```
const variantLogin = (props: Dict) => {
  return {
    bg: theme?.colors?.orange?.main,
    _disabled: {
      bg: theme?.colors?.gray['200'],
    },
    _text: {
      color: theme?.colors?.white,
      _disabled: { color: theme?.colors?.gray['500']}
    },
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using variants from functions instead of declaring them as objects.
If you declare them as objects (ex):

```
 primary: {
  background: 'colors.primary.main',
  _text: {
    color: colors.text.main,
  },
  _disabled: {
    backgroundColor: colors.background.main,
    _text: {
      color: colors.text.disabled,
    },
  },
},
```

Or you can use only one definition baseStyle and defaultProps and set it dynamically using a function with context props.
IF you use functions but you have defined more than 1 `variable` Native Base is going to take the definition of `_disabled` from `defaultProps.variant`